# Wicket's AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior stops updating after leaving and re-entering the page

Tags: java, web, wicket

I have this behavior added to a component(MarkupContainer)

```
    AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior updateBehavior = new AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(3))
    {


        @Override
        public void onEvent(Component component, IEvent<?> event) {
            // some business logic
        }

    };
```

Somewhere , on the same page I have an AjaxLink which redirects to another page(in whom constructor I pass the actual page as a parameter) and on that page I have a "Back" AjaxLink which redirects me back , calling `setResponsePage(myFirstPage)` .

The problem is that even though , when rendering the page the behavior updates once , it stops updating once at 3 seconds , as was constructed for.No problem faced with the behavior until leaving the page.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution , but I managed to fix it by removing the behavior `onBeforeRender()` of the page and adding again . I declared a field on the page `private int autoUpdateBehaviorId = -1;`

```
public void addUpdateBehavior(Component c)
{
    if(autoUpdateBehaviorId >= 0)
        c.remove(c.getBehaviorById(autoUpdateBehaviorId));


    AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior updateBehavior = new AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(3))
    {

        @Override
        public void onEvent(Component component, IEvent<?> event) {
            // bussines logic
        }
    };
    c.add(updateBehavior);
    autoUpdateBehaviorId = c.getBehaviorId(updateBehavior);
}


@Override
protected void onBeforeRender() {
    super.onBeforeRender();
    addUpdateBehavior(myContainer);
}
```

Comment: I see no reason why this shouldn't work without the workaroud. Can you create a quickstart and attach it to a Jira issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the solution to your problem; but I have implemented the behavior by overriding onConfigure method of the AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior as below.

In my case, I had to update label with a count of current records in queue every 10 seconds.

Following is code snippet:

```
labelToBeUpdated.add(new AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(configurableDelay)) {
        @Override
        public void onConfigure(Component component) {
            String inProgressOutOfTotal = "10/100"; //Business logic to get total count and inprogress count    
            labelToBeUpdated.setDefaultModel(Model.of(inProgressOutOfTotal));

            //Set visibility of the component if needed
        }   
    }
    labelToBeUpdated.setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

Just curious; is it that onEvent is waiting on an event on the component in order to refresh? Since onConfigure is called before the rendering cycle has begun, it is working for me.

**But as Sven Meier has mentioned,** you might still want to work on his advise to get your code with onEvent.